# JavaScript/Cookie Settings to Integrate into my website

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have many different options on my website that I think fall under cookies or JavaScript or maybe both.

When you type in my URL (sample: www.fakeurl.com) it will go to the page where if it is your first time it will ask:

- What is your first name?
- What color do you want the theme of the website to look like every time you see it?
- Etc.

And it will save these settings which then will redirect you to the part of the website that is e.g., blue or green, etc. On the homepage it will say: "Hello John, your last visit was May 8, 2011. Your current theme color is blue. Would you like to edit these preferences?"

If something else is involved say a news article addressing the public instead of saying "Hello everybody" it would say "Hello John", and continue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be getting a few things confused a little. Yes, you probably want to store some information in cookies, to do that you'll likely need to use javascript. What it sounds like you really want to do is build a site in language like php, possibly even with a database.

So cookies store information, javascript runs code. Clear?

Answer (score 0):

This *can* be done with JavaScript but if the user goes on another computer or if they clear they're cookies, all of those settings would be gone. This actually *should* be done with a server-side language, such as PHP, and a database. When a user changes their settings, you could update the database. This would best be done with a login system, but you could just use  the user's IP or something and whenever that IP visits the site, it'll show the settings for that specific IP address, and all of those settings would be stored in the database. I've done this with a login system before and it actually works out pretty good.

Do you know any server-side languages such as PHP? And, is your site hosted on a server with PHP? (most servers these days have PHP on it)

If you decide to go with client-side coding, it will definitely involve cookies and JavaScript since JavaScript sets the cookies. ;)

I hope this helps you get an idea of what you could do.